# How to handle null value of AggregateResult

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I am having a doubt while writting the code. I am using AggregateResult while writting a query.

If AggregateResult is not equal to null then I'm able to write my logic and it is working fine.

But While AggregateResult is null I am not able to do my opeartion. I checked in debug log, and I see if AggregateResult is null then I'm not able to go to that else loop.

For reference I am attaching the code.

```
public static string getFolderName(String objectName, String FolderName){
   String Final_Folder_Name;

   List<AggregateResult> s = (Database.query('SELECT Max(Folder_Append__c) append FROM Frup__c WHERE Object_Name__c=:objectName AND Folder_Name__c=:FolderName'));
   Integer append_num= Integer.valueOf(s[0].get('append'));
   System.debug('Apend Number---'+append_num);

   Integer final_append_num=append_num+1;

    if(s[0].get('append')!=null){
       Final_Folder_Name =  FolderName+'_'+final_append_num;
       System.debug('####'+Final_Folder_Name );                          
    }else{
       System.debug('%%%');
       return FolderName;      
    }  
    return Final_Folder_Name;

}
```

Code isn't coming to else part, eventhough value of s[0].get('append') is null.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

line 5:  `Integer append_num= Integer.valueOf(s[0].get('append'));` seems to be used before any null tests.

Your modified code might then look like this

```
public static string getFolderName(String objectName, String FolderName){
 String Final_Folder_Name;

 List<AggregateResult> s = Database.query('SELECT Max(Folder_Append__c) append FROM Frup__c WHERE  Object_Name__c=:objectName AND Folder_Name__c=:FolderName');


 if (s.size() > 0) {
     Integer append_num =  (s[0].get('append') != null) ? Integer.valueOf(s[0].get('append')) : 0 ;
     System.debug('Apend Number---'+append_num);

     Integer final_append_num=append_num+1;

    // this doesn't make much sense now , left in for clarity
      if(s[0].get('append')!=null){
         Final_Folder_Name =  FolderName+'_'+final_append_num;
         System.debug('####'+Final_Folder_Name );                          
      }else{
         System.debug('%%%');
         return FolderName;      
      }  
  }
  return Final_Folder_Name;
```

}

Comment: @ max :I didn't get you. Can you plz clarify a little bit. :)

Comment: The evaluation for null (ie the `if` test) should be around line 5 where you  access the first element  of the list ( `s[0]` ) 
  You probally require another test for null  on the getter  for 'append' as your code  later   adds 1 to a  value that is potentially  null (   `Integer final_append_num=append_num+1;` )
  I have modified your code in my answer to  reflect where you may require some  defensive checks